# How to check balance of a smart contract in Remix IDE Javascript VM?

Tags: contract-development, remix, balances

I'm working on a smart contract that can hold some ETH.

Currently, I'm unable to see what is its balance in the Remix IDE.

I'm trying to use the console:

[image]

I have access to `web3` but how to check the balance? Or maybe it's somewhere in the UI, that would be even better.

Sample contract that can receive Ether via fallback function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Payable {
    function() external payable { }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can able to check account balance by

web3.eth.getBalance("your contract address")[image: It will work for me. I am using the solidity version but a different web3 version. I think that is the problem. But I don't know why it will not work for you]

Comment: I have used the same solidity compiler version. but a different web3 version. I don't know why it will not work for you

Answer (score 2):

From Remix docs 'web3 is only available if the web provider or injected
provider mode is selected', so you can't use web3 with JavaScript VM.

As a workaround you may add a function that returns this.balance in your contract

Comment: @Stock Market answer works.